# How to apply PIVOT on two columns and translate into one row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two columns in the source table and I am trying to apply pivot to translate into one row. The Name column will be dynamic and I would not know upfront the number of Names and which Names to filter for.

Is it possible to get this query working without specifically looking for 'First Name', 'Last Name' and 'Address1' etc. ?

```
Name in ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Adddres1')
```

Query:

```
select * 
from
(
select 
f.Name, fv.[Value]
from tblValues v
join tblNames n
ON v.NameID = n.NameID
where v.id = 123456
) src
pivot
(Max(Value)
For
Name in ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Adddres1')
) as pivot_table
```

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: I am using SQL Server and  SQL Server Management Studio v18.12.1. Thanks!